# unset array key if certain values are null

Tags: php, arrays

Considering the below array, how can I unset the sub array's that have keys 1 to 7 all with null values. I just can't seem to visualise it in my head how to iterate through it, or if there's a function that will already take care of it.

```
$x = array(
            (int) 1 => array(
                'name' => 'Platemaking',
                (int) 1 => null,
                (int) 2 => null,
                (int) 3 => null,
                (int) 4 => null,
                (int) 5 => null,
                (int) 6 => null,
                (int) 7 => null
            ),
            (int) 2 => array(
                'name' => 'Digital Printing',
                (int) 1 => null,
                (int) 2 => '40.0%',
                (int) 3 => null,
                (int) 4 => null,
                (int) 5 => null,
                (int) 6 => null,
                (int) 7 => null
            ),
        );
```

for example, `$x` should only have one element in this case, which is the sub array index 2

The expected result would be as follows:

```
$x = array(
            (int) 2 => array(
                'name' => 'Digital Printing',
                (int) 1 => null,
                (int) 2 => '40.0%',
                (int) 3 => null,
                (int) 4 => null,
                (int) 5 => null,
                (int) 6 => null,
                (int) 7 => null
            ),
        );
```

Comment: [`array_walk_recursive`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk-recursive.php) with closure should work just fine. Or a callback if you're on PHP < 5.2

Comment: Have you tried something ?

Comment: I've tried a few loops and so on and implemented counters to count the null values, but I'm not getting anywhere. I've drawn a blank on this one

Comment: It would add to the clarity of the question if you also showed your expected result and/or used a different example. Both `2 => array(..)` and `2 => '40.0%'` keys are `2`; it's a little unclear which you want to keep and makes for a confusing example.

Answer (score 1):

Take only the items where at least one element is not NULL

```
$result = array_filter($x, function($val) { unset($val['name']); return array_filter($val);});
print_r($result);
```

**UPDATE**
If listen to deceze, do another version

```
$result = array_filter($x, function($val) { 
         return array_filter(array_intersect_key($val, array_flip(range(1,7))));});
print_r($result);
```

Comment: This one. Simple and effective.

Comment: With the caveat that you're depending on only a `name` key being there. Should that data structure be extended in the future to contain additional keys this algorithm will need to be revised and adapted.

Comment: @deceze Will be rules, will be code. Your answer will be not correct if numder index will be from 5 to 10 . But my stll works :))))))))))))))

Comment: If the requirement specifies keys 1-7 then I'd rather explicitly check for keys 1-7 than for other keys present in the sample. Just pointing that out...

Comment: @deceze I have considered your comment

Answer (score 0):

```
$x = array_filter($x, function (array $sub) {
    return array_reduce(range(1, 7), function ($notEmpty, $i) use ($sub) {
        return $notEmpty || $sub[$i] !== null;
    });
});
```

`array_filter` decides whether the keep the array or discard it; the callback returns whether any of the keys `1` through `7` are not empty (if not empty keep, otherwise discard), it does that by `reduce`ing keys in `range(1, 7)` to a boolean based on whether any of them was `!== null`.

Answer (score -1):

If your array format won't change:

```
foreach ( $x as &$val ) {
    $val = array_filter($val);
}
```

The foreach iterates over the array [by reference](http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php) and [array_filter](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) with no callback will eliminate "falsey" values

Comment: Almost, but I need to unset the array key that holds the 7 null values so I don't end up with arrays of just a single element of 'name'. In the above example, $x should only return one key with sub elements

Answer (score -1):

Found a rather crude solution, but it works

```
            $result = array();
            foreach ($tmp as $k => $v){
                $i = 0;
                if(!((empty($v[++$i]))&&(empty($v[++$i])) && (empty($v[++$i])) && (empty($v[++$i]))&&(empty($v[++$i])) && (empty($v[++$i])) &&
                    (empty($v[++$i])))){
                    $result[$k] = $v;
                }
            }
            return $result;
```

Comment: ಠ_ಠ No. Just no. ಠ_ಠ At least explicitly write `$v[1]`, `$v[2]` etc rather than this obfuscated... thing.